# How to get AWS MWAA Airflow to show a connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I'm trying to set up a Snowflake connection within the AWS MWAA managed Airflow. After reviewing past posts on the topic, it seemed like rebuilding the environment while specifying the latest version of requirements.txt would be the answer. It was not, at least not the whole answer.

I have now successfully rebuilt the environment specifying the updated requirements.txt file, and yet the Snowflake connection is still not an option in the dropdown list.

Here are the contents of my requirements.txt file:

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.4.3/constraints-3.10.txt"

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==3.3.0
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==3.2.1
apache-airflow-providers-google
```

Note that this works fine in the local MWAA runner. I have successfully set up the Snowflake connection locally with the exact same requirements.txt file.

Update - I've done everything listed in the docs, yet the package was not installed on the rebuilt environment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had ran into the similar issue while managing the dependencies at mwaa, for some reason the updated requirements.txt file is not being taken, i have updated the requirements file s3 path and then the dependencies got updated. This is one work around i have found, but will keep you posted if i find any other way.